# Jquery Post Empty Even though Sent Variable has data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The console.log on the first line returns a large array of values. And the Console.log(Data) at the end is displaying the plain text response from the server, but the $_POST variable on the server is empty.

The JS:

```
console.log(topost);
$.post(url,topost,function ( data ){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The console.log(topost);

```
["DiscontentDisciple","illuminatedwax","S2S2S2S2S2","bechus","syncretic","davidreiss666","Skuld","soupyhands","AutoModerator","imluckytometyou","Lord_Arioc","IIdsandsII","Kylnas","alanpugh","langis_on","TheBigDickedBandit","long_wang_big_balls","arnoldlol","SBringer","ExoticCarMan","HaidiMontag","10FootPenis","SupriseRape","AManHasSpoken","ComedicCounterpart","Suddenly_Something","agenthex","GenerallySpecific","WelcomeToTarget","brainswho","Gooflactus","alcakd","Stingray88","TossTime","yolfer","biskits1","Evarg","phishroom","BuccoBruce","LookingForAlaska","getDense","lewisthemusician","tmotom","tha_ape","spankymuffin","Dashing_Pony","RuafaolGaiscioch","BeaverManiac","Careless_Con","Texas_","i_am_sad","The_helpful_idiot","Kon-chezz","bombdailer","frezik","Galifreyan2012","metalshadow","lightpollutionguy","b3mus3d","crazdave","merpes","naked_guy_says","GoodGuyAnusDestroyer","Bibliophobia","Internet_Lynch_Mob","photo","adkoe","ZeitTaicho","movie_man","iamkush","sired_tick","jyjjy","WhipIash","rred82","E_Diddyyy","CYBERPENISATTACK","MJYTR","TheBaconHasLanded","quarktheduck","heroic_trig","sleevieb","Burrow","myhousemateisabitch","promethephile","msm008","daskrip","jonnie123","Legendman3","Makes_Sad_Faces","anxiousalpaca","crankykong","IamDa5id","CocoSavege","iamsofuckedseriously","EvTheSmev","Briscotti","MarkieMarkl","CornishCucumber","BearsStillSuck","government_shill","Ihaveafatcat","gh5046","Sayum","henryponco","bolaxao","mrbriancomputer","PsychicNinja_","poopslooshed","REDDIT-","IVI4tt","spleendor","ngmcs8203","deadbeatbum","vegibowl","workingalot","Black_Apalachi","Incongruity7","rdeari1","ihahp","im_0n_toilet","Andynack","photokeith","Alpha17x","5NL70","AtticusFinch1962","clayvn","anonymau5","coplay","gnarbucketz","BukkRogerrs","teusz16","digital_evolution","theredcheck","empw","OrigamiRock","lumptoast","alphanovember","Nahtanos","som13","rstyknf","jmadden287","patchworkpavements","Computer-Blue","Miltage","bwaxxlo","aussiegolfer","coaltown","ThePickleMan","mpm96","Ilyanep","merreborn","Theemuts","wufoo2","thunderbar","blindado9","ntorotn","CatrickSwayze","HankSinatra","redditbots","Word_Inventor","catbeef","SoLongSidekick","Elefaze","Jinksywinksy","Mordy2011","thatusernameisal","Kanin","inthekeyofbflat","buckygrad","DeaD_bAU5","Toe_Fat","wsright987","Pachi2Sexy","woprdotmil","AmmoBradley","pokelord13","kroutonz","mattoftheD","WipeMyAssWith100s","ShuckBeam","dookyface","XLR8Sam","your_backpack"]
```

The response I get:

```
{"postyn":"YES"}
```

The PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = $value;
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $data['postyn'] = 'YES';
}
```

I don't understand why the $_POST variable is empty?

Comment: I'm an idiot -- Usually helps if I name the value to be sent to the post  $.post(url,{INEEDEDANAME : topost},function ( data ){
    console.log(data);
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url,{**NAMEME**: topost} ,function ( data ){
console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass post data as an array it appears. It needs to either be a string or an object.

Description of data property for jQuery.post():

> data A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.
>
> *From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/*

My guess here based on what you're trying to do is an object. Which brings up the next problem, both an object and your PHP script are expecting both keys and values, but you're only passing values.

You data object should look something like:

```
topost = {
 somekey1: "DiscontentDisciple",
 somekey2: "illuminatedwax",    
 somekey3: "S2S2S2S2S2",
 // etc etc etc
};
```